# Specifying or implementing a type class with variant types in Scala

Tags: scala, variant

I'm new to Scala and need some help for resolving a compilation error:

```
[error] .../traversals  /traversals.scala:120: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Traversable[Tree]
[error]  required: Traversable[Node]
[error] Note: Tree >: Node, but trait Traversable is invariant in type T.
[error] You may wish to define T as -T instead. (SLS 4.5)
[error]             println ("Sorted " + sorted (tree2) (monadApp,inOrder));
[error]                                                           ^
[error] one error found
```

I'm sorry that the MWE is that long, but I translated some type classes in a naive way from Haskell to Scala and stuck when I want to write some example that makes use of them. 
I don't understand the problem exactly, but it seems as if either my `Traversable` trait does not allow that the `T` is replaced by some subtype or the concrete instance `inOrder` or the function `sorted` which uses the instance. As suggested by the compiler I tried to add some `-`s in front of the `T` at the `Traversable` trait, the `Tree` in front of the `inOrder` definition or the `T` in front of `sorted`, but it didn't help.

```
 trait Applicative[M[_]] {
    def pure[a] (x: a) : M[a]
    def comp[a,b] (fx: M[a => b]) (mx: M[a]) : M[b]
    def fmap[a,b] (fx: a => b) (mx: M[a]) : M[b]
        = comp (pure (fx)) (mx)
  }

  trait Functor[F[_]] {
    def fmap[a,b] (f: a => b) (m: F[a]) : F[b]   
  }

  trait Traversable[T[_]] extends Functor[T] {
    def dist[a,M[_]] (t: T[M[a]]) (implicit app : Applicative[M]) : M[T[a]]
    def traverse[a,b,M[_]] (f: a => M[b]) (t : T[a]) (implicit app : Applicative[M]) : M[T[b]] = 
    dist (fmap(f) (t)) (app)
  }

  sealed abstract class Tree[a]
  case class Empty[a] () extends Tree[a]
  case class Node[a]  (x : a, l : Tree[a], r: Tree[a]) extends Tree[a]

  class TreeFunctor extends Functor[Tree] {
    def fmap[a,b] (f: a => b) (t: Tree[a]) =
    t match {
        case Empty () => Empty ()
        case Node (x, l, r) => Node (f (x), fmap (f) (l), fmap (f) (r))
    }
  }

  trait Monoid[A] {
    def mempty : A
    def mappend (x: A) (y: A) : A
  }

  object BoolAnd extends Monoid[Boolean] {
    def mempty = true
    def mappend (x: Boolean) (y: Boolean) = x && y    
  }

  case class K[b,a] (value: b) 

  class MonoidApplicative[m] (implicit monoid : Monoid[m]) extends Applicative[({type λ[α] = K[m,α]})#λ] {
    def pure[a] (x : a) = K (monoid.mempty)
    def comp[a,b] (f : K[m,a => b]) (x : K[m,a]) = K (monoid.mappend (f.value) (x.value))
  }

  case class State[s,a] (func: s => (a,s)) 

  trait Monad[M[_]] {
    def ret[a] (x : a) : M[a]
    def bind[a,b] (mx : M[a]) (fx : a => M[b]) : M[b]
  }

  class StateMonad[S] extends Monad[({type λ[α] = State[S,α]})#λ] {
    def ret[a] (x : a) = State ((s: S) => (x, s))
    def bind[a,b] (mx : State[S,a]) (fx : a => State[S,b]) 
      = State ((s : S) => (((tuple : (a,S)) => (fx (tuple._1)).func (tuple._2)) (mx.func (s))))
  }

  class MonadApp[M[_]] (implicit m : Monad[M]) extends Applicative[M] {
    def pure[a] (x : a) = m.ret (x)
    def comp[a,b] (fx : M[a => b]) (mx : M[a]) : M[b] 
      = m.bind[a => b,b] (fx) ((f : a => b) => m.bind[a,b] (mx) ((x:a) => m.ret (f (x))))
  }

  case class Comp[M[_],N[_],a] (unComp : M[N[a]])

  class CompApp[M[_], N[_]]  (implicit mapp : Applicative[M], napp: Applicative[N])  extends Applicative[({type λ[α] = Comp[M,N,α]})#λ] {
    def pure[a] (x : a) = Comp (mapp.pure ( napp.pure ( x) ))
    def comp[a,b] (mf : Comp[M,N,a => b]) (mx : Comp[M,N,a]) = Comp (mapp.comp (mapp.comp (mapp.pure (napp.comp[a,b]_)) (mf.unComp)) (mx.unComp) ) 
  }

  object Main {  
    implicit def inOrder : Traversable[Tree] = new Traversable[Tree]{
        def dist[a,M[+_]] (t: Tree[M[a]]) (implicit app : Applicative[M]) 
        = t match {
            case Empty () => app.pure (Empty ())
            case Node (x, l, r) => app.comp (app.comp (app.comp(app.pure ((l : Tree[a]) => ((x: a) => ((r: Tree[a]) => Node (x,l,r))))) (dist (l) (app))) (x)) (dist (r) (app))
        }
    }   
    val emptyTree = Empty[Int]()
    val tree2 = Node(5, Node (2, Empty (), Empty ()), Node (9 , Empty (), Empty ()))
    implicit def stateMonad[a] = new StateMonad[a] ()
    implicit def monadApp = new MonadApp[({type λ[α] = State[Int,α]})#λ] () {}
    implicit def andMonoidApp  = new MonoidApplicative[Boolean] () (BoolAnd);
    implicit def stateMonoidComp = new CompApp[({type κ[β] = State[Int,β]})#κ, ({type λ[α] = K[Boolean,α]})#λ ] () (monadApp, andMonoidApp)
    def pairSort (x : Int) : State[Int,Boolean] 
        = State ((y : Int) => (y <= x, x))
    def sorted[T[_]] (t : T[Int]) (implicit as : Applicative[({type λ[α] = State[Int,α]})#λ], tr : Traversable[T]) : Boolean
        = (
           (tr.traverse[Int,Boolean,({type λ[α] = Comp[({type κ[β] = State[Int,β]})#κ, ({type λ[α] = K[Boolean,α]})#λ , α]})#λ] 
            ((i : Int) => 
               Comp[({type κ[β] = State[Int,β]})#κ, ({type λ[α] = K[Boolean,α]})#λ , Boolean] 
                 (as.fmap[Boolean, K[Boolean,Boolean]] ((x: Boolean) => K[Boolean, Boolean] (x)) (pairSort (i)))
            )
            (t) 
            //(CompApp[({type κ[β] = State[Int,β]})#κ, ({type λ[α] = K[Boolean,α]})#λ ])
            (stateMonoidComp)
           ).unComp.func (-10000) 
          )._1.value
    def main (args: Array[String]) 
        =   println ("Sorted " + sorted (tree2) (monadApp,inOrder));

  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you have two different types: `Traversable[Node]` and `Traversable[Tree]`.  This comes from the ADT translation from Haskell. Whereas in Haskell `Node` and `Empty` are both `Tree`, in Scala they are *subtypes* of  `Tree`, which causes the concept of *variance* to come into play: given `A` subtype of `B`, is `T[A]` a subtype of `T[B]`?

If we look at the type of a function `X => Y`, we'll see it is declared `Function1[-X, +Y]`, that is, it is contravariant in `X` and covariant in `Y`. That means a function that takes `Tree` and returns `Node` is a subtype of a function that takes `Node` and returns `Tree`. For example:

```
def f[T](n: Node[T])(func: Node[T] => Tree[T]): Tree = func(n)
def zeroRoot(tree: Tree[Int]): Node[Int] = Node(0, tree, Empty())
f(Node(1, Empty(), Empty())(zeroRoot)
```

The function `zeroRoot` works, because we are passing it a `Node` and it expected a `Tree` (which is ok), and we returned a `Node`, which in turn was returned as a `Tree` (also ok).

Incidentally, `Tree` should probably be co-variant.

Now, one other example of contra-variance is the ordering class. While Scala's invariant because of some technicalities, a proper ordering should be contra-variant. After all, if you know how to order a `Tree`, it follows that you can order a `Node`, so an `Ordering[Tree]` would be a subtype of `Ordering[Node]`, since the first can be passed where the second is expected.

I haven't really paid close attention to the code, but it makes sense that something used as ordering ought to be contra-variant. On the other hand, it doesn't seem possible to make `Traversable` contravariant, since `Functor` type signature requires invariance.

Fix this problem by passing the type `Tree` explicitly to `Sort`, or declare `tree2` explicitly as a `Tree`. Then you'll get other, different problems! :)

Comment: Thank you for your explaination! Anotating the type of `tree2` to be `Tree[Int]` (and adding an `fmap` definition in `inOrder` as a quick solution) made the code compile. And yes, I'm not ordering the tree but only checking whether the elements in an arbitrary traversable structure are ordered in the order the structure is traversed. (Where the elements are assumed to be Integers at the moment.)